# C command line argument check

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have the below part of code in which I noticed that if I change the 0 to 1 the result is the same. I get the `STACKprint();` with "on" as the second argument, nothing with anything else and if there is no argument I get a segmentation fault. I guess for the segmentation fault I need to check if the argument is `NULL` but I am not sure how to do that with the second parameter and it really bugs me out why `(strcmp (argv[2],"on") == 1)` has no effect. Is it not supposed to take a TRUE value?

```
 if (strcmp (argv[2],"on") == 0) {
            STACKprint();
            printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: To prevent the segmentation fault, you need to check `argc`.

Comment: You would use `argc` (a count) to determine if `argv[2]` exists.

Comment: @aschepler  Sorry for stupid question but what is `STACKprint()` ?

Comment: Changing 0 to 1 should change the outcome.  Something else is wrong.  Could you edit your post to include the entire `main()` function, with the 1 in place, and show the output, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to check if there is an argument, you should use the argc variable of the `main(int argc, char** argv)`, which indicates the length of your argv array.

```
if (argc < 3) {
  printf("missing argument\n");
  exit(-1);
}
```

As for `strcmp`, the man page only states that it returns 0 if the two strings in argument are equal, else non-zero... but not necessarily 1. In fact it is implementation dependent. The way to use it to check for string equality is therefore :

```
if (0 == strcmp(argv[2], "on")) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: You mean `argc<3`, since he's using `argv[2]`, right?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the segfault, check the value of `argc` to discover whether `argv[2]` exists.  If `argc < 3`, `argv[2]` wasn't supplied.

`strcmp()` doesn't return true/false; it returns a value either less than, equal to, or greater than zero depending on the relative values of its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>


  int main (int argc, char**argv)
  {
     if (argc >= 3 && strcmp (argv[2],"on") == 1){
  //        STACKprint();
          printf("\n");
      }
  }
```

and you try to run it with `myexe 1 on`, It will never go into the if block
and if you change the 1 to 0, it will go.

Something else is wrong.

It will be nice if you can post your code and the way you are calling it.

Comment: Sure you want  `strcmp (argv[2],"on") == 1` instead of `strcmp (argv[2],"on") == 0` or `strcmp (argv[2],"on") != 0`?

Comment: Good point @chux. This is not going to work as expected (https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp0